# Add native functionality to hybrid apps

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

We have an Ionic app where we want to add a new feature in native. So clicking a button in the app, will launch a plugin just like normal plugins with it on UI etc. However complication comes when I want to navigate freely back and forth from plugin side to Ionic.

Consider these scenarios:

1. Plugin to open a `HTML page` written on Ionic side based on a user
   action. Clicking back on this html page will again land you back to plugin UI.
2. Maintaining `back stack` in Ionic and Android/iOS side so that back navigation happens smoothly.

What I did so far is to use `sendPluginResult` method to pass different codes to Ionic side and open desired pages. In reality it destroys the back stack totally since plugin has exited.

Clicking back button on Ionic side, I actually make plugin method calls again kind of emulating back behavior.

Is there a better way to handle this? Has someone faced similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I understood your question correctly.

Assuming that you can use some variable to check whether this plugin just opened a html-page, you could do something like this:

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(event) {

   if(/* check if plugin just opened html-page here */){
     // if condition succeeds, then do not open same html-page again
     event.preventDefault();
     // go two steps backwards to prevent this plugin to open same html-page again
     history.go(-2);
     // update your variable
     // ...
   }

},100);
```

Hope it helps.